# Should I change veterinarians?

Tags: dogs, health, veterinarian

English Mastiff developed round infected lump and swelling in web between first toes that made walking difficult, one year ago.

Vet said it was cheek grass and did surgery. Found nothing. Sore between toe continued to be infected and rupture. Vet opened and cleaned. Sore did not go away.

Vet put dog on antibiotics for 8 months. Sore reduced in size, but remained and continues to rupture. Smells fowl, but It has not grown in size and seems localized. Vet has not diagnosed it as cyst nor did biopsy.

Dog has not been able to go on a walk for a year now. Last visit, vet wants to do more explore surgery.

Vet charges for each visit, treatment and medications. Vet wants to be paid at time of service.

It has been a year, I am broke. I say remove it and repair web best you can.

I need advice: should I change vets? Please and thank you.

Comment: https://www.petmd.com/blogs/fullyvetted/2009/february/interdigital-cysts-and-their-god-forsaken-therapies-6722 and https://www.merckvetmanual.com/dog-owners/skin-disorders-of-dogs/abscesses-between-the-toes-interdigital-furunculosis-in-dogs seem possibly relevant to you.

Comment: If in doubt you could get a second oppinion by visiting another vet once. You don't need to change them before you know the second vet's approach